# Why does Visual Studio sometimes disallow code from continuing after an error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, debugging

When Visual Studio breaks on an unhandled error in console applications, it will not let execution continue normally so you are forced to address the error in some way (such as setting a value in the Immediate window to avoid a null reference error) or you must set the next statement to be executed to another line of code, or just end execution altogether.

In Asp.Net applications, this is usually not the case. It will usually allow you to continue execution which generally causes your browser to go to your error page. However, on some occasions I find that it doesn't do this and I have to restart my application rather than just let it continue to the error page.

One option I'm given is to uncheck the "Break when this exception type is thrown", but of course I don't want to do that because I do want it to break... I just want to let it continue after it breaks and I hit F5.

Currently I'm in this situation and it's very annoying because it's on a lambda expression where I can't (or I don't think it's possible to) change the next statement to be executed in order to get past the error which means I must end execution and start the application again.

What is the logic here that prevents Visual Studio from continuing in cases like this? And is there any solution I'm missing that would allow me to continue without restarting the application?

Comment: The OS itself kills a process if there's an unhandled exception. ASP.NET *handles* the exceptions even if the user's code doesn't, to prevent the web app from shutting down just because one action failed. The request handling middleware actually wraps the action call in a `try/catch`

Comment: `it doesn't do this and I have to restart my application rather than just let it continue to the error page.` what occasions? What was that code doing? That kind of unhandled error will bring down the entire application if you continue anyway

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos In this case it was just a null reference error in a lambda expression. I understand what you're saying about the OS killing it and being wrapped in a try/catch to prevent bringing the whole app down. I just don't understand why it doesn't continue on with that try/catch which should result in responding with an error page to the browser, but instead behaves as it would in a console application where that extra try/catch layer doesn't exist.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I should add, in this specific case the error is occuring within a call from a controller that is located within a try/catch block, so actually it doesn't even need to go to the middleware. I would expect it ought to bubble up to the try/catch in the controller but as long as the debugger is attached it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways you can get a debug break and that popup:

- You triggered an exception, but it's handled in a `try..catch` somewhere upstream. You only get the break and the popup if you explicitly enable the exception in your exception list, and you can safely continue from it to the exception handler.
- You triggered an exception, but it's not handled by anything at all. In that case you'll always get the exception popup, regardless of your exception filter settings, and you will be unable to proceed from there. Your application is officially dead, and the next instruction will terminate it, regardless of what you edit in memory. All you can do is inspect the state of your application and perform some limited operations because of your unstable stack status.
- You triggered a *native* exception, like access violation or stack overflow. That is *bad*, and again there is no coming back from this. But it's even worse because your managed stack trace is no longer accesible, you are stuck in the native world and the next instruction will terminate your application.

Comment: This is the first option, where there is a try/catch around the code in question. However, I cannot figure out how to make it continue onto the catch... pressing F5 does not cause it to proceed to the catch. I will note that the code is not "directly" in the try/catch, but it should bubble up to one. It's also in a lambda expression. Lastly I will mention that there is no async code involved here. So am I missing something here, or does this sound like a bug based on my experience (assuming, of course, that my communicates have been clear/accurate)

Comment: To be very clear: both the lambda expression and the line of code that triggers the lambda expression are located in the same method, and the stack trace for that method calls starts in a controller that both has a [HandleError] attribute AND the call is wrapped in a try/catch as well. So I don't see why the debugger will not allow execution to continue.

Comment: Are you sure there's a direct stack trace link between your exception trigger and your catch? That there's no multi-threaded transfers of your exception? You mentioned `HandleError`, Asp.Net does a lot of context transfers between threads internally, maybe that's what you're seeing? I would suggest posting some *very minimal* but complete reproduction code if you can, simply writing it might give you insights into what the problem actually is.